# How to continuously bounce an object when site is live

Tags: javascript, jquery-effects

I am new to JavaScript and jQuery. I have trouble in my new project. I want to need a image is bouncing. I got a script from net. But This function is only for jumping on the click.I want its jumping when the site is loaded. Please help me.

Link http://www.tycoonlabs.com/help/bouncing%20-%20Copy.html

This is my script

```
<SCRIPT>
$(function(){
    $('#bouncy1').click(function () {
          $(this).effect("bounce", { times:5 }, 300);
    });
});
</SCRIPT>
```

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have it bounce while something is happening and then stop it, you could use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval)

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){ 
    jQuery('#someId').effect('bounce', {times: 5}, 300);
}, 500); // every half second

// Do some stuff to load up your site;        

clearInterval(interval); // Stop the bounce interval
```

You may want to adjust the `times` parameter and the `delay` to meet your needs and effect.

Comment: wow...Thanks you ,Thank you very much. Last 4 hours ,I am trying to this answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        function bounceObject(obj)
        {
            obj.effect("bounce", { times:5 }, 300);
        }
        bounceObject($('#bouncy1'));
        $('#bouncy1').click(function () {
            bounceObject($(this));
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

this works well

```
function bounce(){
    $('#test').effect( "bounce", "slow", bounce);
}
bounce();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xGe2D/